# Pure Javascript get alt value of image onclick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and am having troubles using JQuery, therefore i've opted for the route of using pure javascript instead. I've looked through numerous questions / answers here but they all tend to move towards giving JQuery answers with regards to getting attributes from "this".

I have this line, which i want to use to get the attribute from the specific image that i click on.

```
altName = (this).getAttribute("alt");
```

Currently it does nothing, but i'm struggling to fix it without trying to implement JQuery.

Tag

```
<img className = "video img-responsive" src = "assets/back.png" alt = "monday-1" onClick={this.gotoNthVideo}/>
```

ReactJS function

```
gotoNthVideo: function(event){
    gender = "female";
    altName = (this).getAttribute("alt");
    //currentLocation = "assets/" + gender + "/" + altName + "/";
    alert(altName);
  },
```

Is the javascript completely wrong, or does it just need some tweaking? This is one of the first times i've used pure javascript over Jquery so i'm not 100% sure how "this" actually works.

EDIT: I meant to remove .val(), it wasn't in my source code.

Comment: Do you mean `$(this)` ?

Comment: `altName = event.target.getAttribute("alt")`. The `val()` method looks like jQuery and doesn't exist in standard DOM APIs. Even if it did it's to get a `value` of an input element. `getAttribute()` returns the string you're looking for.

Comment: Scratch the old comment, this works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <img id="image1" src="SampleImage.png" alt="Suitcase" />
</body>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('image1').addEventListener("click", function(e){
        alert(e.target.alt);
    });

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm not trying to add an id for every single image, given that there are a lot. I want to be able to get the alt value from any image, rather than having to write 30 listeners.

Comment: @CSafari , I think you missed what I was demonstrating-  just use `alert(e.target.alt);`. I know you are using react, the html and adding of the event was simply to get a working demo that you could copy and paste to look at.

Comment: I see what you mean, and it does help. The person above also gave me a line that worked,  thanks for the help anyway.